# change forgotten password page blank

Tags: magento-1.8, password-recovery

Clicking the link on a password reset email leads to the /customer/account/changeforgotten/ page, but it is blank.

Pretty sure this worked in the past, only changes recently were SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7405 v1.1

Any suggestions on how I should diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what broke the password reset.  SUPEE-6788 introduced a change to the customer.xml template which I needed to propagate to my theme's customer.xml.  Apparently SUPEE-6788 renamed things in that .xml file,  see the diff below:

```
156c157
<     <customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
---
>     <customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
175c176
<             <block type="customer/account_changeforgotten" name="changeForgottenPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
---
>             <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
177c178
<     </customer_account_changeforgotten>
---
>     </customer_account_resetpassword>
```